# LiteDB ideal class setup for updating part of a document

Tags: c#, nosql, litedb

This is my first usage of LiteDB and NoSQL. I am trying to represent the following relationships:

- There is a collection of `User`s
- There is a collection of `Groups`s
- Each `Groups` can contain multiple users.
- Different `Groups`s can contain the same users.

If I approach it as such using DbRef:

```
class User
{
     [BsonId]
     int Id { get; set; }

     string Name { get; set; }
     ...etc
}

class Group
{
     [BsonId]
     int Id { get; set; }

     [BsonRef("users")]
     List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't seem unreasonable, but what would be the way to

- add a single user to a group? find the group, add the user, then update the group?
- remove a user from the database? remove it from Users collection, then go over all the groups and remove it from each?

Is there a way to do it without deserializing and reserializing the entire `Group`? What is the idiomatic way to do this in NoSQL?

### Update

Thinking about it more, I realize it has nothing to do with DBRef.
the same problem would stand if each `Group` just had a collection of some primitive data type, e.g. `int`.